# Visual C++ error C2059 for template parameter use in class declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++

The following:

```
template <int A>
class __declspec(align(A)) alignable {
};
```

Does not compile with Visual Studio, but works fine with GNU (using `__attribute__` instead of `__declspec`). The compiler doesn't seem to be able to resolve the template parameter `A` when used as part of the class declaration, gives the error "C2059: syntax error: identifier".

I'm beginning to wonder whether this is valid C++, since `A` is being used within the same statement that it is declared. What puzzles me is that GNU allows this; I've been through the "Templates" section of the standard, but can't seem to find anything explicit about this.

**Edit:** Since a class can derive from one of its template parameters, it would seem sensible to me that template parameters are available in the class declaration.

Comment: Reading the C++ standard won't tell you how Microsoft's `__declspec(align(A))` works and it won't tell you how GNU's `__attribute__` stuff works. You have to read the compiler's documentation for its non-standard extensions.